# How do I search for a "short time" data type using SQLin java?

Tags: java, sql, datetime, ms-access

This program is for my A-level so that's why its a leisure centre booking system. I have a database with a table for gym bookings. One of the columns of this table is entry time which I want to be able to search. I'm guessing I'm using incorrect syntax for the SQL query.

**This is the bit of the code where I call the SQL method i have in another class.**

```
    }System.out.println(Selected);
        ArrayList<Booking> currentBookings = BookingSQL.Bookings("SELECT * FROM GYM WHERE BookingDate = '" + Selected + "' AND EntryTime = '13:00'");
        for (int i = 0; i < currentBookings.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(currentBookings.get(i).toString());
        }
}
        }
```

---

**This is the SQL method I am using to search the table**

```
public class BookingSQL {
    public static ArrayList<Booking> Bookings(String sql) {
        ArrayList<Booking> CurrentBookings = new ArrayList<Booking>();
        String DatabaseLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\ProjectDatabase.accdb";
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + DatabaseLocation, "", "");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            ResultSet Rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = Rs.getMetaData();
            while(Rs.next()){
                Date dateformat= Rs.getDate(2);
                Booking newBooking = new Booking(Rs.getInt(1), Rs.getDate(2).toLocalDate(),
                        Rs.getTime(3).toLocalTime(), Rs.getTime(4).toLocalTime(), Rs.getInt(5));
                CurrentBookings.add(newBooking);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }return CurrentBookings;
    }
}
```

---

[This is a screenshot of the table in access I'm searching from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PzAi.png)

I tried using just the usual format from the table of just 13:00, but obviously that didn't work so tried a few other formats I could think of. Then after enough failures I tried using a java.sql.time variable and adding that into the sql query but it gave me the same response.

Every time I run it i get this error from my try, catch.

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::5.0.1
> incompatible data types in combination

Comment: Unrelated, but please use PreparedStatement whenever you’re passing variables into SQL. Don’t do manual string concatenation. Read about SQL Injection

Comment: Remove `System.out.println(e);` and replace it with `e.printStackTrace();`.  A stack trace is much more useful—it will tell you (and us) exactly which line of your code generated the exception. After you’ve run it that way, edit your question and show us the entire stack trace, including any “Caused by” parts.

Comment: Are you using UCanAccess? [It supports `LocalTime` since version 5.0.0](https://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html#change).